# ¿Transformacion de punteros?

Tags: c++, punteros, abogado-del-lenguaje

Tengo una duda sobre los punteros.

Al declarar un puntero sea `short`, `int`, `float`, etc este lo podemos pasar a un puntero `void` ¿porque?. Y ¿como se testea para hacer lo opuesto?. Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio!, considera revisar [ask] y realiza modificaciones a tu pregunta para que puedas obtener la ayuda deseada en el sitio, . No olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Answer (score 8):

Un puntero a `void*` es un puntero genérico, es decir, puede apuntar a cualquier tipo de dato.
Por ejemplo:

```
int x = 9;
void* px = &x;
```

En ese ejemplo, le estás asignando la dirección de memoria de la variable "x" al puntero "px".
Para poder escribir/leer algún dato en la variable "x" a través del puntero, debes hacer un casting (el compilador necesita saber a que tipo apunta el puntero) al puntero genérico al momento de desreferenciar.

```
int x = 9;
void* px = &x;
*(int*)px = 10;
```

Para hacer el proceso inverso es muy sencillo, mirad este ejemplo:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 9;
    void* px = &x;
    *(int*)px = 10;

    int* y = (int*)px;
    //Resultado en pantalla: 10
    printf("%d\n", *y);
    return 0;
}
```

Si te puedes dar cuenta, es necesario hacer un casting al momento de asignar el contenido de "px" al puntero "y", dado que el compilador de C++ nos obliga a hacer una conversión explicita (algo que en lenguaje C es innecesario).

**EDIT:**

El motivo de porqué se necesita hacer un casting al momento de desreferenciar un puntero genérico, es debido a que, el compilador necesita calcular un offset a través de ese tamaño en bytes y de ese modo, crear el modo de direccionamiento adecuado para poder calcular la dirección de memoria de un elemento en específico.

Por ejemplo:

```
int main(void)
{
    char n[5] = {"ABCD"};
    void* pn = n;
    for(int i = 0; i != sizeof n; ++i)
        printf("%c\n", *(pn + i));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Ese código no compilaría, porqué el compilador no sabe cual es el tipo de dato al que apunta el puntero genérico, de eso depende que se pueda calcular correctamente la dirección de memoria del dato.
Ahora que pasaría si engañamos al compilador y hacemos esta conversión explicita:

```
for(int i = 0; i != sizeof n; ++i)
    printf("%c\n", *((double*)pn + i));
```

Asumiremos que las direcciones de memoria del arreglo `n` son:

```
|0x01| |0x02| |0x03| |0x04| |0x05|
  A       B      C      D     \0
```

Entonces, el código de arriba debería imprimir los caracteres A, B, C, D, pero eso no ocurrirá porqué se estaría calculando otras direcciones de memoria que no corresponde al arreglo de caracteres.

Antes de comprobar el porqué, necesitamos comprender esta parte:

```
*((double*)pn + i)
```

El compilador interpretaría esa sentencia de esta forma:

```
*((double*)pn + i* 8)
```

Se multiplica por 8 bytes porqué el tamaño de un tipo double es de 8 bytes. Básicamente esto lo hace el compilador para obtener el offset necesario y así poderlo sumar a la dirección base del búfer y de ese modo hallar la dirección de memoria del elemento.

Entonces, sabiendo esto, ¿qué pasaría si la variable `i` vale 1? ¿Obtendrá la dirección de memoria del caracter `B`? La respuesta sería no. Cuando i valga 1, la expresión sería evaluada de esta manera:

```
//Asumiendo que puntero el pn apunta a la dirección 0x01.
*(0x01 + 1* 8)
*(0x01 + 0x08)
*(0x09)
```

El resultado fue `0x09`, pero si revisamos la tabla de ejemplo, la dirección de memoria del caracter B es `0x02`, por lo tanto, estaríamos desreferenciando una dirección que ni sabemos si le pertenece al programa, haciéndolo abortar de inmediato (lo más probable que sea así).

Aquí concluimos que es fundamental especificar a que tipo apunta el puntero genérico, ya que de ese modo, se va a generar una dirección de memoria que sea correspondiente a lo que se quiere acceder.

La solución del ejemplo anterior sería:

```
for(int i = 0; i != sizeof n; ++i)
    printf("%c\n", *((char*)pn + i));
```

**¿Cuando no es necesario especificar el tipo al que apunta el puntero a void*?**

Pues cuando un puntero tiene más de un nivel de direccionamiento indirecto (es decir, habrá más trayectos para llegar al dato) no se necesitaría especificar el tamaño, siempre y cuando no se acceda al dato.

Por ejemplo:

```
int main(void)
{
    char* n[5] = {"AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE"};
    void** pn = n;
    for(int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", *(pn + i));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

En este ejemplo, se declara un arreglo de punteros de tipo char, luego, se le pasa la dirección base del arreglo al puntero doble `pn`.

Hay que recalcar que `pn` no es un puntero genérico. El puntero `pn` apunta a un puntero genérico de tipo void*, que a su vez apunta a un dato de cualquier tipo (int, float, char, entre otros).

El código de arriba compilaría, porqué el compilador conoce el tamaño en bytes (a lo que apunta `pn`), en este caso podría ser 4 o 8 bytes, esto depende de la arquitectura de la máquina (si es de 32 bits o 64 bits).

Si analizamos esta línea:

```
printf("%d\n", *(pn + i));
```

Y además, asumimos que compilamos este ejemplo en una máquina de 32 bits, el compilador interpretaría este código de esta forma:

```
printf("%d\n", *(pn + i* 4));
```

Aquí el tamaño en bytes es conocido, porqué el compilador sabe que la dirección de memoria que se va a calcular es la de un puntero, no la de un dato.

Pero si ahora hacemos esto:

```
for(int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
    printf("%c\n", *(char*)*(pn + i));
```

En este caso es fundamental especificar el tamaño, porqué queremos acceder a la dirección de memoria de un caracter, no la de un puntero.

**¿Cuando podemos utilizar un puntero genérico?**

Pues eso dependerá del problema que quieras resolver, por ejemplo, si quisiéramos crear una función que reserve memoria dinámica para la creación de una matriz dinámica, sería ideal usar punteros genéricos, ya que, la matriz podría ser de cualquier tipo.

Por ejemplo:

He creado dos funciones, una función para crear una matriz dinámica de cualquier tipo (ya sea integer, float, short, etc.), además de eso, también se creó la subrutina para liberar la memoria reservada.

La función `CrearMatriz`:

```
void** CrearMatriz(int filas, int columnas, size_t size)
{
    //Se reserva memoria para las filas (que en realidad es un arreglo de punteros).
    void** n = (void**)malloc(filas * sizeof *n);
    if(n == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Hubo un problema al momento de asignar memoria para las filas\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i != filas; ++i)
    {
        //Se reserva memoria para las columnas (que en realidad es el array dinámico al que apuntará un puntero X del arreglo de punteros).
        n[i] = (void*)malloc(columnas * size);
        if(n[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error: Hubo un problema al momento de asignar memoria para las columnas\n");
            //Se debe liberar la memoria hasta lo que se haya reservado
            liberar(n, i);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Para liberar la memoria:

```
void liberar(void* p, int filas)
{
    void** n = (void**)p;
    //Se libera cada array dinámico al que apunta un puntero X del arreglo de punteros
    for(int i = 0; i != filas; ++i)
        free(n[i]);
    //Se libera el arreglo de punteros
    free(n);
}
```

Modo de uso:

```
int main(void)
{
    int** i;
    float** f;
    //El sizeof **i es equivalente a sizeof(int)
    i = (int**)CrearMatriz(5, 10, sizeof **i);
    if(i == NULL) return 1;
    //El sizeof **f es equivalente a sizeof(float)
    f = (float**)CrearMatriz(2, 5, sizeof **f);
    if(f == NULL)
    {
        //Se debe liberar la primera matriz que se haya reservado dinámicamente.
        liberar(i, 5);
        return 1;
    }
    liberar(i, 5);
    liberar(f, 2);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se te ha olvidado explicar para qué se usa el puntero genérico

Comment: Solo añadir que el motivo que el compilador necesita saber el tipo para extraer un valor, es que el puntero solo indica la posición de memoria donde empieza algún dato, pero si no sabe si ese dato es entero, una cadena de caracteres, etc. el compilador no sabe cuantos bytes tiene que extraer para formar el dato. Un puntero genérico solo te indica dónde está el dato, pero no donde acaba. Además de eso con un puntero genérico tampoco puedes aplicar aritmética de punteros, por ejemplo *(px + 2).

Answer (score 1):

> Al declarar un puntero sea `short`, `int`, `float`, etc este lo podemos pasar a un puntero `void` ¿por qué?.

Porque esas son las normas. Según [el estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/n4830.pdf), `void` es un tipo especial (traducción mía):

> #### 6.7.1 Tipos fundamentales
>
> 13. El tipo *`cv`*`void` es un tipo incompleto que no puede ser completado; dicho tipo tiene un conjunto vacío de valores. Cualquier expresión se puede convertir explícitamente al tipo tipo *`cv`*`void`. Una expresión del tipo tipo *`cv`*`void` únicamente debe ser usada como expresión, como operando de una expresión separada por comas, como segundo o tercer parámetro del operador `?:`, como operando del `typeid`, `noexcept` o `decltype`, como expresión de retorno en una función cuyo tipo de retorno sea *`cv`*`void` o como operando de una conversión explícita a tipo *`cv`*`void`.

El puntero a `void` también tiene normas especiales (traducción mía):

> #### 7.3.11 Conversión de punteros
>
> 2. Un valor de lado derecho puro (*prvalue*) de tipo “puntero a *`cv`*`T`”, donde `T` es un tipo objeto, puede ser convertido a *prvalue* de tipo “puntero a *`cv`*`void`”. El valor del puntero permanece inalterado tras la conversión.

---

> Y ¿Cómo se testea para hacer lo opuesto?.

No se puede. Cualquier conversión a `void` pierde la información del tipo original así que no existe ningún test para comprobar el tipo que un puntero a `void` pudiese haber tenido (o no) previamente. Eso si, la conversión de puntero a `T` después a puntero a `void`  y de nuevo puntero a `T` es segura.